# Removing extraneous semicolons from string in PHP

Tags: php, filter, strip

I have a variable $collectors which can contain from one to seven peoples names separated by semicolons.  If the string houses a single name then it will be followed by seven semicolons, if it houses two names then 5 semicolons.  How can I strip out the extraneous semicolons that are at the end of the string while leaving the ones separating the actual peoples names in place?

Examples of data held in $collectors
    John Doe;;;;;;;
    John Doe;Jane Doe;;;;;;
    John Doe;Jane Doe;Bob Smith;;;;;
    etc.

Comment: `$collectors = rtrim($collectors, ';');` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: Whilst you can certainly trim the string, perhaps you should look at how you are generating the variable in the 1st place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those names can be at every position in the CSV string you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$strippedSemicolonStr = preg_replace('/;+/', ';', $str);
```

Be aware that with this solution it's possible to have a string ending with a `;` because it just removes duplicate semicolons.

If all names are at the begining of the CSV string (without gaps) you can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$strippedSemicolonStr = rtrim($str, ';');
```

With this solution you'll loos any semicolons at the end of the string. So the new string won't end in a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim function, found in many languages, to remove specified characters from the beginning and end of strings.

```
$string = 'John Doe;;;;;;;';
$string = trim ( $string, [";"] );
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php